# Positive semidefiniteness of a matrix -to examine convexity- What mistake have I made?

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      e^{x_1x_2} & x_1, x_2 \geq 0 \\
      +\infty & otherwise \\
   \end{cases}$

The Hessian of this matrix is:
$H = \begin{pmatrix} x_2^2e^{x_1x_2} & x_1x_2e^{x_1x_2} \\ x_1x_2e^{x_1x_2} & x_1^2e^{x_1x_2} \end{pmatrix}$

Using sylvestor's criterion to examine positive semi-definiteness;

$\checkmark$ $x_2^2e^{x_1x_2} \geq 0$

$\checkmark (x_1x_2)^2(e^{x_1x_2}) - (x_1x_2)^2(e^{x_1x_2}) = 0$

Therefore the matrix is positive semidefinite, is it not?

The suggested solutions indicate the function is convex, and hence the hessian is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: If a function is convex then its Hessian is indeed positive semidefinite (provided differentiability).

Comment: So are you saying that this function is convex? My question is whether I've made a computational error in finding out if the hessian is positive semidefinite or not

Comment: The Hessian is positive semidefinite (your computation is correct), and hence the function is convex.

Comment: I do not believe your Hessian is correct. I think the $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ terms are $(x_1x_2+1)e^{x_1x_2}$.

Comment: I forgot to use product rule - I am stupid.. thank you.

Comment: I believe you will find that the correct Hessian is *not* positive semidefinite.

Comment: Also, you're use of Sylvester's criterion is not quite correct. To test for positive *definiteness*, you must see if all leading principal minors are *positive*. To test for positive *semidefiniteness*, you must see if *all* principal minors are nonnegative---not just the leading ones. For an $n\times n$ matrix, that's $n$ tests for positive definiteness, and $2^n-1$ tests for semidefiniteness.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to point out the leading principal minors and the principal minors in my example for me? I have looked up the definitions on countless sources but still am only able to vaguely interpret what is being said